# Optimising Julia ODE model

Tags: julia

I'm currently trying to learn Julia but translating some of my code. Below, I exemplify with what kind of problems I'm usually confronted, i.e. small- to medium-sized systems of ODEs tested with a large battery of inputs and forcing functions. Here, I'm using `ModelingToolkit.jl` but I'm not sure whether this is the best way.

I'd appreciate any input on how to improve this code.

```
using DataFrames, DifferentialEquations, ModelingToolkit

# ModelingToolkit
@variables t xc(t) xp(t) u(t);
@parameters kel k12 k21;
D = Differential(t);

# Parameters
p = [kel => 1,
     k12 => 2,
     k21 => 1];

# Initial conditions
x0 = [xc => 0,
      xp => 0];

tspan = (0, 10);

# ODEs
odes = [D(xc) ~ -kel*xc - k12*xc + u + k21*xp,
        D(xp) ~           k12*xc + u - k21*xp];

# Stimulus function
# My function
function myfun(t, dose, duration)
    if t >= 0 && t <= duration
        dose
    else
        0
    end
end
@register myfun(t, dose, duration)

stim_size = [1, 2, 3];
stim_length = [1, 2, 3];

# Loop over stimulations
sol = DataFrame();

for i in 1:length(stim_size)
      for j in 1:length(stim_length)

            # Define ODE
            @named sys_ij = ODESystem([u ~ myfun(t, stim_size[i], stim_length[j]); odes])
            prob_ij = ODEProblem(structural_simplify(sys_ij), x0, tspan, p)
            sol_ij = solve(prob_ij)
      
            # Convert to dataframe and add stimulations
            sol_ij_df = DataFrame(sol_ij)
            sol_ij_df[!, :size] = repeat([stim_size[i]], size(sol_ij_df, 1))
            sol_ij_df[!, :length] = repeat([stim_length[j]], size(sol_ij_df, 1))

            # Combine
            append!(sol, sol_ij_df);
      end
end
```

Comment: Your example is not "minimal" in the sense that the problem does not have to do with the loops (I think). Can you solve the IDE individually? The TypeError is probably due to `e.g. t > 1` being an expression, not a boolean, if `t` is a variable.

Comment: When `myfun` is not in the loop, I don't get the error.

Comment: In any case, the error definitely happens when you call `myfun(t)` in the definition of `sys_ij` because the `if`-statement fails on expressions, which are not booleans. I'm not sure what the code looks like where you don't get the error...

Comment: Removing both for loops and manually setting I = j = 1. Then there's no error.

Comment: "Removing both for loops and manually setting I = j = 1. Then there's no error." Cannot confirm, I get the same error if I do that.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I've rewritten the code by taking `myfun` out of the loop and at least for me, the error is gone.